# Does a stuffing bit in CAN count towards the next stuffing group

Tags: can-bus

If you have a sequence of bits in CAN data:

011111000001

There will need to be a stuffed 0 after the ones, and a stuffed 1 after the 0s. But I'm not sure where the 1 should go.

The standard seems ambiguous to me because sometimes it talks about "5 consecutive bits during normal operation", but sometimes it says "5 consecutive bits of data". Does a stuffing bit count as data?

i.e.

should it be:

011111**0**00000**1**1

Or

011111**0**0000**1**01

Comment: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CAN_bus) gives a good explanation with examples. What part of the wikipedia page is unclear?

Comment: @Lundin That does give a good example, and does explicitly state my situation. But Wikipedia isn't an actual source, which is why I wasn't using it - I could easily change it to say the exact opposite. That's why I was hoping to find an official standard that confirmed it (which I still haven't).

Comment: The very same link mentions the name of the standard, ISO 11898-2. You can find a free, older draft version that's mostly the same if you search for "Bosch CAN 2.0B"

Comment: Perhaps 11898-2:2016 makes it clear, but I don't believe the Bosch standard sufficiently answers the question. It states that "Whenever a transmitter detects five consecutive bits of identical value in the bit stream to be transmitted it automatically inserts a complementary bit in the actual transmitted stream." I personally think the use of the word "actual" makes it ambiguous - it suggests that "bit stream to be transmitted" and "actual transmitted bit stream" are different things, in which case it could be interpreted that the first option in my question is correct

Comment: Yes of course they are different things, that's the whole point of the bit stuffing chapter you quote from. "Bit stream" is the data to be transmitted and "actual bit stream" is that data with padding bit(s) appended. I'll post an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bit stuffing only applies to the CAN frame until the ACK-bit. In the End-Of-Frame and Intermission fields, no bit stuffing is applied.

It does not matter *what* is transmitted.

It is simply "after 5 consecutive bits of the same value" one complementary bit is inserted.

The second of your examples is correct. 6 consecutive bits make the message invalid.

Comment: That does seem to agree with what I've found in general, and I can now this is the third unofficial source to confirm it. So that will do unless I find otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

From the old Bosch CAN2.0B spec, chapter 5:

> The frame segments START OF FRAME, ARBITRATION FIELD, CONTROL FIELD, DATA FIELD and CRC SEQUENCE are coded by the method of bit stuffing.

Meaning everything from the start of the frame to the 15 bit CRC can have bit stuffing, but not the 1 bit CRC delimiter and the rest of the frame.

> Whenever a transmitter detects five consecutive bits in the bit stream to be transmitted

This "bit stream" refers to all the fields mentioned in the previously quoted sentence.

> ...in the actual transmitted bit stream

The actual transmitted bit stream is the original data + appended stuffing bit(s).

Comment: Under a strict interpretation of what you've said, the first example in my answer is correct. The "bit stream to be transmitted" is, partially: "1111100000". In the 0s, "five consecutive bits" is not reached until the end. But because of the 1s, the situation has changed. That is only known because of the contents of the "actual transmitted bit stream". So it should actually say "five consecutive bits in the actual transmitted bit stream".

Comment: @richjhart Look, it's not rocket science. If there are 5 bits of the same value, then a stuffing bit of the opposite polarity is inserted. Period. The spec might assume that the reader knows basic data communication as taught at uni, because bit stuffing is an universal concept not exclusive to CAN. You have it in and all manner of other low level protocols too, like for example HDLC. Works exactly the same there, 5 bits as well.

Comment: The whole point of a standard is to not assume any knowledge on the part of the reader. There are different ways to do bit stuffing, and it would be legitimate to do it either way. Just because it works exactly the same in other standards does not mean this standard would automatically be the same. I find it interesting that it explicitly says that bit stuffing doesn't apply to some parts of the message - to me that makes the question more legitimate as well. You said "a stuffing bit... is inserted. Period". Well doesn't that qualification mean that it's not always the case?